# C# Failed try-catch very slow in Visual Studio IDE

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Does anyone know how to stop the following problem:

Sometimes you have to use a Try-Catch block to see if a value can be converted to the expected type.  For example, if you don't know the original value is a string you cannot just use TryParse.

Unfortunately, i have just discovered a Visual Studio IDE quirk that is making life difficult.

To see this, create a Winforms project and add the following code to the form load:

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch(); stopWatch.Start();
        int numTries = 1000;

        object obj = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < numTries; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                int val = (int)obj;
            }
            catch (System.InvalidCastException)
            {
            }
        }

        TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
        string elapsedTime = $"{numTries} failed try-catch took a time of {ts.Hours:00}:{ts.Minutes:00}:{ts.Seconds:00}";

        MessageBox.Show(elapsedTime);
    }
```

When I run this in my IDE it takes 17 seconds for the code to process 1000 failed try-catch blocks.  In contrast, if I run the debug version outside the IDE the time taken is too small to even register.  This is a problem for code debugging of the editor I am working on.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise, Version 15.4.0, .NET Framework 4.7.02046

Comment: "Sometimes you have to use a Try-Catch block to see if a value can be converted to the expected type" That´s allmost *allways* a bad idea. There are better approaches, that mostly begin with `TryParse`.

Comment: No, you don't need a try/catch to discover if you can convert that object to an integer. There is Int32.TryParse to avoid a costly exception

Comment: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidcastexception(v=vs.110).aspx):  _An InvalidCastException exception is caused by developer error and should not be handled in a try/catch block; instead, the cause of the exception should be eliminated._

Comment: What is the exception in your *real* code? In this case, it's easily avoided - we can't tell whether or not it's similarly avoidable in your real case without more information.

Comment: Also [see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert(v=vs.110).aspx) !

Comment: In reply to the above:  In other parts of my code I am also using the convert class, and it has the same performance issue in the IDE.  Wrt using TryParse that is a lot quicker but in my real code the original value is not guaranteed ti be a string.  It is a value in a data cell, and I don't easily know what type it is.

Comment: OMG the answers here are awful. Goes to show that simplifying the test is always a good idea so the nerds don't pick on the usecase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem using Visual Studio is most likely your debugging analysis. Exception are very expensive to handle, and even more with an IDE attached.

You should use proper code to try to convert the string, instead of relying on exceptions.

If you are not sure what data type it is, you can improve by checking the type on beforehand.

```
if (obj is int i)
{
    // use i
}
else
{
    string s = obj.ToString();

    if (int.TryParse(s, out int val))
    {
        // use val
    }
    else
    {
        // your exception case
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, the OP code is silly and as he wrote he works on an editor the assumption is not far-fetched. But you are correct..

Comment: @KirkLarkin Sorry, I saw the `object obj = "";` for a `string` variable. If OP corrects that, it should work.

Comment: Please my see my comments above.  The object is not guaranteed to be a string.

Comment: What can it be? @AntWaters

Comment: It is a value in a cell in a DataGridView.  I am writing generic validation code for user entered data.